# Jira Json to dataframe with Python. Issue with one column which stays as json

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe

In a specific column of my dataframe it does not convert to json and it stays like that

[{'self': 'https://servicedesk.com/rest/api/2/c', '**value**': 'EXANDAS', 'id': '10120'}]

How can i grab only the **value**  or convert that column two three more columns in the existing dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column is a list of dicts you can do

`df[col].map(lambda x: x[0]['value'])`

to get the values

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got this error:

df1['fields.customfield_10208'].map(lambda x: x[0]['value'])

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: can you post df.head()